# Silex Authentication Firewall Issue

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I've looked through the silex documentation http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html and I'm using HTTP Authentication to allow a single user into the backend of a system.

Although this works on the local copy, it doesn't on the server, refusing to login. I've had this issue before, when using a htpasswd file, and was able to fix this by running php in cgi mode, but that didn't help in this instance.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'http' => true,
        'users' => array(
             // raw password is foo
             'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg==')    ,
        ),
    ),
    )
));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with the headers which contain the authorisation data in php-cgi on Apache. This could be your problem. Try adding a .htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Source : [Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php#L47)